# getting form input data in multi-page table in php

Tags: php

i am new to PHP so please bear with me.

in my php project using mysqli queries i get results from mysql database and display them "as an html table with pagination" (e.g. 10 results per page).

my main piece of code to achieve that is the code below and works fine:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td> word-combinations </td>
  </tr>   
  <?php 
    while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) { ?>
   <td><?php echo $row['words'],$_POST['fname'];?></td>                        
 </tr>
  <?php } ?> <!-- end of while loop -->
  <?php ?>  <!-- the end of php tag  -->
</table>
```

so the url of first page of the table is :
http://example.com/mytable.php?page=1

the url of second page of the table is :
http://example.com/mytable.php?page=2
and so on.

i also have created an **start.php** page which contains a "simple HTML form" with a "single input field" with POST action:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo "<form method='POST' action='http://example.com/mytable.php?page=1'>";
 echo "<label for='fname'>First name:</label>";
 echo "<input type='text' name='fname'> <br>";
 echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
 echo "</form>";
?>
```

**My goal is to be able to get (access) the string user entered in the input field of start.php page on all pages of table and append that string to the end of all results of the table pages when is displays to the user.**

so to achieve this I've used php **session** concept.

when user fills out the input filed and hit submit button, user is redirected to http://example.com/mytable.php?page=1 url and the **$_POST['fname']** value is present and is successfully added at the end of the results of the first page of the table.

when user fills out the input filed and hit submit button, user is redirected to http://example.com/mytable.php?page=1 url and the **$_POST['fname']** value is present and is **successfully** added at the end of the results of the first page of the table.

but when user clicks on the same page1 pagination link (actually  tag) under the table, the $_POST['fname'] **is not present anymore** !

also when user clicks on next pages links (page2, page3, etc)  $_POST['fname']  **is not present anymore** !

My piece of code to create "pagination links" under table are:

```
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
echo "<a href='mytable.php?page=".$i."'> $i </a>";
}         
?>
```

I don't know where I am wrong.
whether I need to place some code in somewhere to make **session_start();** be executed on all pages of the table?

or for a reason which i don't know, the **$_POST['fname']** can not be retrieved on all pages of the table.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `$_POST` array is only populated when you submit a form using the `method="POST"`, it won't be populated if you click directly on a link. If you are building up the form contents in session variables, then that's where you would retrieve the data from when your user clicks on page links without submitting a form.

Comment: use get to do this kind of things in a quick way. You will have to repeat the query in each page using offset (so first 50 rows in the first page then from 51 to 100 and so on). Other way is to use ajax to do the same in a single page

Comment: Rather than storing this value into the session, it might make more sense to add it to your pagination links. `mytable.php?page=123&fname=valueyougotviaPOSTonfirstpage`. You will need to access it using $_GET and not $_POST then. But you can use $_REQUEST to access parameters that were send using _either_ GET or POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all guy who guided me.

so according to your guidance i change the form action from POST to default **GET**.

then according to **CBroe** guidance i added $_GET['fname'] into pagination link code.

in this way seems there is no need to deploy php sessions at all.

```
<?php
  $userinput = $_GET['fname'] ;
  for ($i=1;$i<=$total_pages;$i++){
  echo "<a href='mytable.php?page=".$i."&fname=$userinput'> $i</a>";
  }         
?>
```

now everything works fine as expected but i don't know whether my codes and settings are perfect!

thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not setting the $_SESSION data after starting the session_start.
Your can try this..........But the Processor will be on the same page:.
1)create File to fetch the data....."index.html".....

```
<form action="index2" method="post">
```

2)Process the form When the user hit submit....."index2".....

```
<?php
 session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['name1'])){
$_SESSION['name1']=$_POST['name1'];
}else{
echo "There is no Data in the Variable";
```

}

3)Now the SESSION variable will be absent in all the script you just have to start the session in each page, but i recommend using a one script processor page